# Why I can't connect through SSH to my EC2 instance? Permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh

I created EC2 within my VPC that has a public subnet
[image]
I used standard security group settings

[image]

When I try to SSH

```
ec2_user@3.123.36.129: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

My route table routes(I have Internet Gateway)
[image]

Why did I got denied permission?
What should I check regarding my subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the permissions of the .pem file so only the root user can read it hope might this work in your case as most of the time we have to give permission to pem file.

```
sudo chmod 400 ~/.ssh/ec2private.pem
```

Comment: 1) In private subnet security group give access only to the public subnet CIDR Range

2) SSH into the public subnet

3) Add the keypair contents into .pem file into the instance(example: vi test.pem)

4) Giving permissions using “chmod 600 test.pem”

5) Now “ssh ec2-user@private-ip-address -i test.pem”

did you also try this.